# Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object

Tags: php, html, dom

I have been checking around alot on how to work around this error but did not have much luck. I basically have a couple XML files that may or may not have specific fields. I am running a couple functions that check for these fields and print the info out. My objective is that, if the field exists print the info otherwise skip it and move to the next record.

Here is the function I have running that traverses through the XML:

```
function pull_xml($id, $gettag = false, $tagname = 'field', $checkatt = array(), $attname = false, $gettextnode = false) {
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->loadXML(PRIVATE_DIR. "jobs/$id/job.xml");
    try {
        if ($xml) {
            if (!$gettag)
                return $xml;
            $tags = '';
            $makecsv = true;
            echo $tagname;
            if ($xml->documentElement->getElementsByTagName($tagname)!= 0) {
                $tags = $xml->documentElement->getElementsByTagName($tagname);
                foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                    if ($checkatt) {
                        if (!$tag->getAttribute($checkatt[0]) || (string)$tag->getAttribute($checkatt[0])!= $checkatt[1]) {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($attname) {
                        foreach ($tag->attributes as $k => $v) {
                            if ((string)$k == $attname)
                                return (string)$v;
                        }
                    }
                    else if ($gettextnode) {
                        return $tag->textContent;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                $makecsv = false;
        }
        else
            $makecsv = false;
        if (!$makecsv)
            return '--';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how I call this function:

```
foreach ($jobs as $job) {

    $id = (string)$job['job_id'];
    $total = (float)pull_xml($id, true, 'field', array(
            'id',
            'app_dv'), 'value', false);
    $job_totals[$id] = $total;
    $overall_total += $total;

    $casenum = pull_xml($id, true, 'field', array(
            'label',
            'Case Number'), 'value', false);
    $lease_end = pull_xml($id, true, 'field', array(
            'id',
            'lease_end'), 'value', false);
    $date_range = pull_xml($id, true, 'field', array(
            'label',
            'Tax Year'), 'value', false);

    $detail_csv[] = array(
            $comp,
            $casenum,
            $total,
            $lease_end,
            $date_range);
}
```

Any Input at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try removing the `->documentElement` part, just `$xml->getElem...`

Comment: `$xml->documentElement` is not an object.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this comparison:

if ($xml->documentElement->getElementsByTagName($tagname)!= 0)

If nothing is found, getElements returns an empty array which is never equal to the number 0, so this always evaluates to true. Try calling .length on the result of getElementsBy...